# Product grid says "The resource isn't set" when adding __construct to model class

Tags: magento2, model, dependency-injection

I have a model class that I'm trying to inject a ScopeConfigInterface into, and after compiling di, the product grid says **"The resource isn't set."** My class extends 
`\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` and implements `\Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface`, `\myCompany\myModule\Api\Data\MyEntityInterface`.

Errors in  `var/system.log`:

```
[2017-03-15 22:36:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-03-15 22:36:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-03-15 22:36:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2017-03-15 22:36:51] main.CRITICAL: The resource isn't set. [] []
```

The only thing I've added to the class is the new `__construct()` code.  Here is my code.

```
protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('\myCompany\myModule\Model\ResourceModel\MyEntity');
}

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wasn't in accord with the parent class' constructor. The surprising thing is magento setup:di:compile yielded no error. Anyway, here's the solution.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
```

Comment: setup:di:compile worked for me.